# Center Modal in viable area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building my own custom Modal/Dialog box and I wanted to center it to the viewable area. For example if the web page is very large and the viewer scrolls down very far and then clicks to open my custom Modal/Dialog box it will open up but then the user will have to scroll to the top to see it. I would like for the Modal to open up in the center of the viewable area. Can someone show me how to calculate the center of the viewable area, so that when the modal is shown it can be positioned there absolutely.

Twitter bootstrap does this with their Modal where it slides down to the center of the viewable are and I would like to do the same with my custom widget,

Answer (score 0):

For example I'm using something like this:

```
$(function() {
  /**
   * Moves an element to the center of the current screen (considering scrolling)
   */
  $.fn.center = function (position) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
      var t = $(this[i]);
      t.css("position", position || "absolute");
      var extra_top = position != "fixed" ? $(window).scrollTop() : 0;
      var extra_left = position != "fixed" ? $(window).scrollLeft() : 0;
      t.css("top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - t.outerHeight()) / 2 + extra_top) + "px");
      t.css("left", Math.max(0, ($(window).width() - t.outerWidth()) / 2 + extra_left) + "px");
    }
    return this;
  }

...
});
```

Usage: `$("#modal").center();`

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this would be to see the height and width of your modal window.
then, set **position to fixed**

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: - "INSERT WIDTH DIVIDED BY 2"
margin-top: - "INSERT HEIGHT DIVIDED BY 2"
```

this will always center the modal on the page.

```
.page{
    position: absolute;
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.modal{
     width: 300px;
     height:300px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:red;
}
```

see my attached jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/yxTSh/

Comment: yeah fixed position is not an option because sometimes the modal will be bigger then the screen size and the user will never be able to see the parts that are not initially visible.